# Advanced Collaboration with Google Maps

Tags: google-maps, customization

Is there a way for me to create a custom Google Map for my website which the public may add markers to but may not remove markers that other people have already placed.

So are there any permissions I can edit to allow people to add but not remove markers?

Answer (score 0):

You can use google map as a basemap and create your own layer in order manage it from your own server using eg mapserver and/or geospatial database such as PostGIS and openlayers on the front end. This way you will have a full control over who can add what and you can do it outside of googlemaps API sandbox